# Time of events based on curve

Tags: calculus

I have a sine formula where y is the time and x is the average event activity compared to peak activity. Formula:

$y = \sin(4 \pi x) (\frac{9}{8} - x)(\frac{3}{10}) + \frac{7}{10}$

$x$ from $0$ to $1$ represents $ 24$ hours.

If I know the specific number of events, say there are $14400$ total events, how can I map out the time for each event? My first line of thought was to use calculus but I'm a little out of shape.

Comment: simply plot the curve? I guess that's the easiest way??

Comment: The y coordinate is the % of activity based on peak activity. Any value of x returns a number between 0 and 1. I think what I'm after involves more.

Comment: Suggest you edit the post based on your comment.

Comment: If you plot the equation given, you'll see there are places where 6 values of $x$ produce a single value of $y$. So if you know $y$ and want to find out $x$ you won't get a unique value (except at one point, $y \approx .4737$). BTW the range of $y$ is about .4737 to about 1.0009. I'm guessing you want to range to be from 0 to 1. If so you'll need to adjust your formula.